# Unable to pass intent in Custom array Adapter class

Tags: android

Guys I am Unable to pass intent in Custom array Adapter class, I had used the same thing.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RandomGameTableActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

It shows the error : the constructor intent is undefined in android.

Comment: you have to use activity context reference in custom adapter.

Comment: pass the context in Adapter and use it as : `Intent i = new Intent((YouActivityName)context, RandomGameTableActivity.class)`

Answer (score 1):

Modify Your Code

**From**

`Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RandomGameTableActivity.class);
startActivity(i);`

**To**

`Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RandomGameTableActivity.class);
getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context in Adapter :

```
public CustomAdapter(Context _context)
{
    context = _context;
}
```

And use it as :

```
Intent i = new Intent((YouActivityName)context, RandomGameTableActivity.class);
```

Hope it helps ツ